# Tailwind preset is outputting css, but not showing styles on the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, preset

Please help me understand why the preset is outputting css to the output file but not showing the styles in the browser. If I write plain CSS in `newstyle.css` it outputs to `output.css` and shows in the browser.

I tried adding `tailwind.preset.js` to `content:[]` in `tailwind.config.js` but its not necessary. I tried removing `mode: 'jit'`, but it had no effect.

Is there something that needs to be added to `postcss.config.js`?

```js
// package.json

{
  "name": "project-tailwind",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "tailwindcss sandbox",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "postcss source/newstyle.css -o public/output.css -w"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6"
  }
}

// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    content: [
        './public/index.html',
        './public/**/*.{html,js}'
    ],
    presets: [
        require('./tailwind.preset.js')
    ]
}

// postcss.config.js

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
}

// tailwind.preset.js

module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
      content: [
        './public/index.html',
        './public/**/*.{html,js}'
    ],
    theme: {
      colors: {
        blue: {
          light: '#85d7ff',
          DEFAULT: '#1fb6ff',
          dark: '#009eeb',
        },
        pink: {
          light: '#ff7ce5',
          DEFAULT: '#ff49db',
          dark: '#ff16d1',
        },
        gray: {
          darkest: '#1f2d3d',
          dark: '#3c4858',
          DEFAULT: '#c0ccda',
          light: '#e0e6ed',
          lightest: '#f9fafc',
        }
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Graphik', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      extend: {
        flexGrow: {
          2: '2',
          3: '3',
        },
        zIndex: {
          60: '60',
          70: '70',
          80: '80',
          90: '90',
          100: '100',
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
/* newstyle.css */

.preset {
    @apply font-sans;
    @apply text-pink-dark;
}

a {
    color: chartreuse;
}

/* output.css */

.preset {
    font-family: Graphik, sans-serif;
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(255 22 209 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

a {
    color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tailwind Sandbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/output.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="font-sans text-pink-dark">Welcome to the Tailwind 3.1 Sandbox!</h1>
    <h2>These headings utilize custom base directives</h2>
    <h3>The sizes can be freely manipulated from the tailwind.config.js file</h3>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Link to something</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime quibusdam deleniti expedita asperiores provident eum sequi, nam laborum veritatis non?</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>
            Container
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                Flex 1
            </div>
            <div>
                Flex 2
            </div>
            <div>
                Flex 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                Flex 1
            </div>
            <div>
                Flex 2
            </div>
            <div>
                Flex 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                Grid Col 1
            </div>
            <div>
                Grid Col 2
            </div>
            <div>
                Grid Col 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button>
        Click me
    </button>
    <button>
        Click me
    </button>
    </div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Blue Button</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Other button</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Another button</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this `/public/output.css` most likely is wrong maybe only `output.css` or `./output,css`

Comment: If `/public/output.css` was wrong then the pure css on the `<a>` tag would not work. That is the correct file path.

Comment: in the SO snippet everything above `body` is ignored

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to communicate but I'll just reiterate that the file path is sound. I tested pure css styles in the `newstyle.css` file. They output to `output.css` and show in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if a custom preset is created, the relevant directives must be added to the source stylesheet, so in my very basic sample preset, the `@tailwind utilities` directive had to be added to `newstyle.css` to use the `font-sans` and `text-pink-dark` custom utility classes.